# convert numpy.ndarray minutes to datetime

Tags: python, numpy, datetime

I am trying to convert a numpy.ndarray of minutes from one month to datetim.
I used this:

`import datetime as dt`

`mins = data[:, 0];`

`year = int(self.yyyymm[0:4]);`

`month = int(self.yyyymm[4:]);`

`time['time'] = dt.datetime(year,month,1) + pd.TimedeltaIndex(mins['minutes'], unit='m')`

But I go this error:

time['time'] = dt.datetime(year,month,1) + pd.TimedeltaIndex(mins['minutes'], unit='m')

IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Somebody had similar problem and found to to solve it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The index error is clear, you can not index a numpy array with a string.

Comment: @obchardon should I convert this numpy array to something else that it could be able to do what I want?

Comment: @nuvolet This code is not reproducible as given. Please respect the rules of SO's code posting to get help from others

Comment: @nuvolet one other piece of advice: you should put all your code in one block instead of separating the lines + specify the python language